# I want to Scatter the requests but not Gather results into single payload unlike how scatter-gather does in Mule

Tags: mule, mule-studio, mule-el, mule-component

I have a flow like:

```
 <flow name="Flow1">
    <set-payload value="Important Message" />
    <scatter-gather>
        <choice doc:name="A">
           <when expression="true">
            //TODO
           </when>
           <otherwise>
            //TODO
           </otherwise>
        </choice>
        <flow-ref name="B" />
    </scatter-gather>
    <logger message="from flow-ref B: #[payload]" level="INFO" doc:name="response from B only"/>
 </flow>
```

Right now the payload that comes out is an array of Payload;But I need only payload from response of B. I don't want to append java class to iterate over the payload to find B response.
I don't want the response from choice component but only from flow-ref B.
How to achieve this? Is this possible in an easy way using only mule components?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you want the payload "Important Message" to reach the flow-ref to B, and you also want the choice to occur?

Try getting rid of the scatter-gather and wrapping the choice router in an [Async Scope](http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/current/Async+Scope+Reference) instead.